# How to create an image button in a form in twitter boostrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently, I've images such as this:

```
    <img src="xyz.jpg"  width="80" height="80" id = "wp" alt="wp">
 <img src = "abc.jpg"  width="80" id = "tm" height="80" alt="tm">
```

and then writing the onclick on it:

```
$('img#wp').click(function() {


});
```

The problem with this is I'm not able to use this to insert a value into a form depending upon the image that has been clicked. Nor do the image show up as button, thus not exactly responsive for mobiles and tablets. How to go about it?

Comment: well - first, it's my understanding that there are no "click" events in mobile development - you should look into jquery mobile (specifically **vclick()** events).  this is from their mobile docs: _The idea behind virtualized mouse events is to translate touch events into mouse events to compensate for the missing mouse event triggers. Developers should be aware that these virtualized mouse events will not prevent any synthetic mouse events from being triggered inside the browser after a touch event._

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<button>` to submit forms, and also include an image tag inside of the button

```
<button name="buttonName" value="buttonValue" type="submit">
   <img src="xyz.jpg" alt="" />
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [image submit button](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms14.htm)

```
<input type="image" src="http://www.luvvitt.com/skin/frontend/default/luvvitt/images/submit.png" alt="Submit Form" class="btn"/>
```